# Python pandas correlation corr() TypeError: Could not compare ['pearson'] with block values

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, correlation, pearson

```
one = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4,5], index=[1,2,3,4,5])

two = pd.DataFrame(data=[5,4,3,2,1], index=[1,2,3,4,5])

one.corr(two)
```

I think it should return a float = -1.00 but instead it's generating the following error:

> TypeError: Could not compare ['pearson'] with block values

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.corr` computes pairwise correlation between the columns of a single data frame. What you need here is [`pandas.DataFrame.corrwith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html):

```
>>> one.corrwith(two)
0   -1
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You are operating on a `DataFrame` when you should be operating on a `Series`.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: one = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4,5], index=[1,2,3,4,5])

In [3]: two = pd.DataFrame(data=[5,4,3,2,1], index=[1,2,3,4,5])

In [4]: one
Out[4]:
   0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5

In [5]: two
Out[5]:
   0
1  5
2  4
3  3
4  2
5  1

In [6]: one[0].corr(two[0])
Out[6]: -1.0
```

Why subscript with `[0]`? Because that is the name of the column in the `DataFrame`, since you didn't give it one. When you reference a column in a `DataFrame`, it will return a `Series`, which is 1-dimensional. The documentation for this function is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.corr.html).

Comment: ty brian for your explanation. i see why it works for this example - for some reason, it didn't plug and play seamlessly into my larger piece of code, not sure why yet.